How to compile successfully a rasberry pi pico project using cmake
I am learning how to use the raspberry pi pico (the one with the rp2040). Since I do not want to use VS code, I am doing everything from command line. I have installed the sdk and wrote a simple code to blink the onboard LED. The had part comes with the compilation.
My CMakeLists.txt file is the following:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

include(pico_sdk_import.cmake)

project(blink C CXX ASM)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
pico_sdk_init()

add_executable(blink blink.c)

pico_add_extra_outputs(blink)

target_link_libraries(blink pico_stdlib)

Everything is fine with cmake. When I run cmake .. from the build directory. Then I get errors with make -j4, specifically:
[  1%] Building ASM object pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/CMakeFiles/bs2_default.dir/compile_time_choice.S.o
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S: Assembler messages:
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:13: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.syntax'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:89:  Info: macro invoked from here
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:14: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cpu'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:89:  Info: macro invoked from here
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:15: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.thumb'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:89:  Info: macro invoked from here
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:22: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.thumb_func'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:100:  Info: macro invoked from here
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:101: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1 `{lr}'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:107: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r3,=0x40020000'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:108: Warning: `r0' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:108: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:109: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:109: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:110: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r0,[r3,'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:111: Warning: `r1' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:111: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:112: Error: no such instruction: `bics r0,r1'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:113: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:113: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:114: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:114: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:115: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:115: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:116: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:116: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:118: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r3,=0x18000000'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:121: Warning: `r1' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:121: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:122: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:122: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:125: Warning: `r1' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:125: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:126: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:126: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:134: Warning: `r1' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:134: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:135: Warning: `r2' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:135: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:136: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:136: Error: too many memory references for `str'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:147: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r1,=((7<<16)|(0x0<<8))'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:148: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:148: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:151: Warning: `r1' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:151: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:152: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:152: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:155: Warning: `r0' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:155: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:156: Error: no such instruction: `bl read_flash_sreg'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:157: Warning: `r2' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:157: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:158: Error: operand size mismatch for `cmp'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:159: Error: no such instruction: `beq skip_sreg_programming'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:162: Warning: `r1' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:162: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:163: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:163: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:166: Error: no such instruction: `bl wait_ssi_ready'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:167: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r1,[r3,'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:170: Warning: `r1' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:170: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:171: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:171: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:172: Warning: `r0' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:172: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:173: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:173: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:174: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:174: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:176: Error: no such instruction: `bl wait_ssi_ready'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:177: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r1,[r3,'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:178: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r1,[r3,'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:179: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r1,[r3,'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:183: Warning: `r0' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:183: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:184: Error: no such instruction: `bl read_flash_sreg'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:185: Warning: `r1' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:185: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:186: Error: no such instruction: `tst r0,r1'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:187: Error: no such instruction: `bne 1b'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:192: Warning: `r1' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:192: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:193: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:193: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:210: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r1,=((0x2<<21)|(31<<16)|(0x3<<8))'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:211: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:211: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:213: Warning: `r1' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:213: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:214: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:214: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:224: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r1,=((8<<2)|(4<<11)|(0x2<<8)|(0x1<<0))'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:225: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r0,=(0x18000000+0x000000f4)'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:226: Error: number of operands mismatch for `str'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:228: Warning: `r1' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:228: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:229: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:229: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:231: Warning: `r1' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:231: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:232: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:232: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:233: Warning: `r1' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:233: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:234: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:234: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:237: Error: no such instruction: `bl wait_ssi_ready'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:243: Warning: `r1' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:243: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:244: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:244: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:261: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r1,=((0xa0<<24)|(8<<2)|(4<<11)|(0x0<<8)|(0x2<<0))'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:262: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r0,=(0x18000000+0x000000f4)'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:263: Error: number of operands mismatch for `str'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:265: Warning: `r1' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:265: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:266: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:266: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/exit_from_boot2.S:16: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1 `{r0}'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/exit_from_boot2.S:17: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/exit_from_boot2.S:18: Error: no such instruction: `beq vector_into_flash'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/exit_from_boot2.S:19: Error: no such instruction: `bx r0'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/exit_from_boot2.S:21: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r0,=(0x10000000+0x100)'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/exit_from_boot2.S:22: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r1,=(0xe0000000+0x0000ed08)'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/exit_from_boot2.S:23: Error: number of operands mismatch for `str'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/exit_from_boot2.S:24: Error: no such instruction: `ldmia r0,{r0,r1}'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/exit_from_boot2.S:25: Error: no such instruction: `msr msp,r0'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/exit_from_boot2.S:26: Error: no such instruction: `bx r1'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/wait_ssi_ready.S:11: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1 `{r0'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/wait_ssi_ready.S:16: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r1,[r3,'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/wait_ssi_ready.S:17: Warning: `r0' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/wait_ssi_ready.S:17: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/wait_ssi_ready.S:18: Error: no such instruction: `tst r1,r0'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/wait_ssi_ready.S:19: Error: no such instruction: `beq 1b'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/wait_ssi_ready.S:20: Warning: `r0' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/wait_ssi_ready.S:20: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/wait_ssi_ready.S:21: Error: no such instruction: `tst r1,r0'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/wait_ssi_ready.S:22: Error: no such instruction: `bne 1b'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/wait_ssi_ready.S:24: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1 `{r0'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/read_flash_sreg.S:16: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.thumb_func'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/read_flash_sreg.S:18: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1 `{r1'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/read_flash_sreg.S:19: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/read_flash_sreg.S:19: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/read_flash_sreg.S:21: Error: missing ']'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/read_flash_sreg.S:21: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/read_flash_sreg.S:23: Error: no such instruction: `bl wait_ssi_ready'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/read_flash_sreg.S:25: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r0,[r3,'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/read_flash_sreg.S:26: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r0,[r3,'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/asminclude/boot2_helpers/read_flash_sreg.S:28: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1 `{r1'
/home/mastermind/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:282: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.ltorg'
make[2]: *** [pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/CMakeFiles/bs2_default.dir/build.make:75: pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/CMakeFiles/bs2_default.dir/compile_time_choice.S.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1771: pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/CMakeFiles/bs2_default.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2

As I have said, I am still learning, but I know a bit of assembly. From the make output is like is not able to understand arm assmebly I think...
Can anyone know how to fix this or knows a better way to tackle the problem?

Have you installed gcc-arm-none-eabi and friends (or another recommended compiler), as mentioned in the README and SDK manual? If you haven't already, I'd also suggest deleting the build directory, to make sure that the cmake config is clean, and trying again without the -j4. (The pico-sdk is pretty clean and well-written, this is more just to eliminate possible variables.)

My interpretation of that prodigious stack of error messages is that the assembler you're using expects a different assembly language than the one in which the assembly files in your SDK are written.  Does the SDK documentation specify an assembler or toolchain to use?  Does it bundle one?

Have you exported all the environment variables specified in the SDK docs? E.g., export PICO_SDK_PATH=/opt/pico-sdk and so on? The pico assembler is pioasm and it is provided in the SDK -- so it appears from the errors that your build is not finding it. I do all my pico builds from the command-line. If you have a 2nd pico, you can use it as a debug probe and flash straight from the command line using openocd. Very nice timesaver.

Try adding include ($ENV{PICO_SDK_PATH}/external/pico_sdk_import.cmake) as the 2nd line in your CMakeLists.txt file. (after providing a correct export PICO_SDK_PATH=/opt/pico-sdk to wherever your SDK is installed)
